# Renaming classes in node collection using for loop not working

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function renameClass() {

        a = document.getElementsByClassName('day');
       for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
          a[j].className = 'test';  
        }; 

    }

</script>



<div class="day" id="1">DÃY A</div>
<div class="day" id="2">DÃY B</div>
```

....
   ..
    DÃY C

```
<button onclick="renameClass()"> rename all classes</button>

and this is result:
/*
<div class="test" id="1">DÃY A</div>
<div class="day" id="2">DÃY B</div>
```

...
    DÃY B
    DÃY C */

```
<button onclick="renameClass()"> rename all classes</button>
```

the number of result is 6, but all of them is 12. why it only rename 6 class?
help me, plz

Comment: Because, `getElementsByClassName()` returns live nodes collection. Use backward `for` or `while`.

Comment: Thank you so much. but it's still errors

Answer (score 1):

As Tushar pointed out in the comment, `getElementByClassName()` returns a [live node collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). What this means is changes to the DOM are reflected in the collection.

When you loop through the collection and change a className, the live collection updates and your loop's index is thrown off.

For example, on the first iteration of the loop, the first element's className is changed to `test`. The live node collection is updated and now includes 1 less element. That is, the collection contains elements 2-6 of the original collection.

On the second iteration of the loop it changes the className of `element[1]`, which is the 3rd element in the original collection. The live node collection is updated and now includes 4 elements (elements 3-6 of the original collection).

On the 3rd iteration of the loop it changes the className of `element[2]`, which is the 5th element of the original collection.

The result is only half the elements have the new class applied.

To get around this you can loop through the elements in reverse order.

```js
var renameClass = function() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('day');
  for (var j = a.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    a[j].className = 'test';  
  }; 

}
```

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="renameClass()"> rename all classes</button>


<div class="day" id="1">DÃY A</div>
<div class="day" id="2">DÃY B</div>
<div class="day" id="3">DÃY C</div>
<div class="day" id="4">DÃY D</div>
<div class="day" id="5">DÃY E</div>
<div class="day" id="6">DÃY F</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I were a lady, I would love you. you're great!